# Vue3 Suspense Parent > Child Animation

Tags: javascript, vue.js, async-await, vuejs3, vue-suspense

I would like to leverage [Vue3 Suspense](https://vuejs.org/guide/built-ins/suspense.html#combining-with-other-components) to initiate a loading state at the parent level that triggers animations in the children. When the request resolves at the parent level, I would like to remove the animation from the children.

App Header:

```
router-view(v-slot="{ Component, route }")
  template(v-if="Component")
    transition(:name="route.meta.transition" appear)
      KeepAlive
        Suspense
          component(:is="Component")
          template(#fallback='')
            div.loading-div LOADING !!
```

Parent Template:

```js
<template lang="pug">
section.discover-row
  div.discover-row-carousel
    DiscoverItem(
      v-for="(item, index) in DiscoverItemStore.automobiles"
      :key="item._id" 
      :item="item"
      :index="index"
    )
</template>

<script setup>
...
import { useDiscoverItemStore } from "@/stores/DiscoverItemStore"
const DiscoverItemStore = useDiscoverItemStore()
DiscoverItemStore.fetchItems()
</script>
```

Child Template:

```
Suspense
  template(#default='')
    div.item SHOW SOME STUFF
  template(#fallback='')
    div.loading-div CHILD LOADING !!
```

—

Request (from pinia store):

```js
    async fetchItems() {
      this.automobiles = []
      this.items = []
      this.loading = true
      try {
        
        this.items = await fetch(discoverUrl)
          .then((response) => response.json()) 
        
        this.automobiles = [...this.items.Cars, ...this.items.Suvs, ...this.items.Trucks, ...this.items.Vans]
        this.loading = false
     ...
```

————————————————————

How can I trigger the loading state at the parent level then show `CHILD LOADING !!` on each child instance until the request to `fetchItems()` at the parent level is resolved?

[Here's a codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/p/github/nickbewley/base-app/master?file=%2F.codesandbox%2Ftasks.json&layout=%257B%2522sidebarPanel%2522%253A%2522GIT%2522%252C%2522rootPanelGroup%2522%253A%257B%2522direction%2522%253A%2522horizontal%2522%252C%2522contentType%2522%253A%2522UNKNOWN%2522%252C%2522type%2522%253A%2522PANEL_GROUP%2522%252C%2522id%2522%253A%2522ROOT_LAYOUT%2522%252C%2522panels%2522%253A%255B%257B%2522type%2522%253A%2522PANEL_GROUP%2522%252C%2522contentType%2522%253A%2522UNKNOWN%2522%252C%2522direction%2522%253A%2522vertical%2522%252C%2522id%2522%253A%2522cltyr42a000063b6hop3vnc98%2522%252C%2522sizes%2522%253A%255B82.05364273817773%252C17.94635726182227%255D%252C%2522panels%2522%253A%255B%257B%2522type%2522%253A%2522PANEL_GROUP%2522%252C%2522contentType%2522%253A%2522EDITOR%2522%252C%2522direction%2522%253A%2522horizontal%2522%252C%2522id%2522%253A%2522EDITOR%2522%252C%2522panels%2522%253A%255B%257B%2522type%2522%253A%2522PANEL%2522%252C%2522contentType%2522%253A%2522EDITOR%2522%252C%2522id%2522%253A%2522cltyr42a000023b6h7ct2kh68%2522%257D%255D%257D%252C%257B%2522type%2522%253A%2522PANEL_GROUP%2522%252C%2522contentType%2522%253A%2522SHELLS%2522%252C%2522direction%2522%253A%2522horizontal%2522%252C%2522id%2522%253A%2522SHELLS%2522%252C%2522panels%2522%253A%255B%257B%2522type%2522%253A%2522PANEL%2522%252C%2522contentType%2522%253A%2522SHELLS%2522%252C%2522id%2522%253A%2522cltyr42a000043b6hvkcmbaoi%2522%257D%255D%252C%2522sizes%2522%253A%255B100%255D%257D%255D%257D%252C%257B%2522type%2522%253A%2522PANEL_GROUP%2522%252C%2522contentType%2522%253A%2522DEVTOOLS%2522%252C%2522direction%2522%253A%2522vertical%2522%252C%2522id%2522%253A%2522DEVTOOLS%2522%252C%2522panels%2522%253A%255B%257B%2522type%2522%253A%2522PANEL%2522%252C%2522contentType%2522%253A%2522DEVTOOLS%2522%252C%2522id%2522%253A%2522cltyr42a000053b6h1o64ma4y%2522%257D%255D%252C%2522sizes%2522%253A%255B100%255D%257D%255D%252C%2522sizes%2522%253A%255B63.411808788319505%252C36.588191211680495%255D%257D%252C%2522tabbedPanels%2522%253A%257B%2522cltyr42a000023b6h7ct2kh68%2522%253A%257B%2522id%2522%253A%2522cltyr42a000023b6h7ct2kh68%2522%252C%2522tabs%2522%253A%255B%257B%2522type%2522%253A%2522FILE%2522%252C%2522filepath%2522%253A%2522%252F.codesandbox%252Ftasks.json%2522%252C%2522id%2522%253A%2522cltyr752600bz3b6h1ye1022s%2522%252C%2522mode%2522%253A%2522permanent%2522%252C%2522state%2522%253A%2522IDLE%2522%257D%255D%252C%2522activeTabId%2522%253A%2522cltyr752600bz3b6h1ye1022s%2522%257D%252C%2522cltyr42a000053b6h1o64ma4y%2522%253A%257B%2522id%2522%253A%2522cltyr42a000053b6h1o64ma4y%2522%252C%2522tabs%2522%253A%255B%257B%2522type%2522%253A%2522TASK_PORT%2522%252C%2522taskId%2522%253A%2522serve%2522%252C%2522port%2522%253A8080%252C%2522id%2522%253A%2522cltyr5z50009b3b6hd31reiv0%2522%252C%2522mode%2522%253A%2522permanent%2522%252C%2522path%2522%253A%2522%252F%2522%257D%255D%252C%2522activeTabId%2522%253A%2522cltyr5z50009b3b6hd31reiv0%2522%257D%252C%2522cltyr42a000043b6hvkcmbaoi%2522%253A%257B%2522id%2522%253A%2522cltyr42a000043b6hvkcmbaoi%2522%252C%2522activeTabId%2522%253A%2522cltyr5wz000773b6hg3xybtjb%2522%252C%2522tabs%2522%253A%255B%257B%2522id%2522%253A%2522cltyr42a000033b6h6ta117c7%2522%252C%2522mode%2522%253A%2522permanent%2522%252C%2522type%2522%253A%2522TERMINAL%2522%252C%2522shellId%2522%253A%2522cltyr43al001udlji66oo36h1%2522%257D%252C%257B%2522type%2522%253A%2522TASK_LOG%2522%252C%2522taskId%2522%253A%2522serve%2522%252C%2522id%2522%253A%2522cltyr5wz000773b6hg3xybtjb%2522%252C%2522mode%2522%253A%2522permanent%2522%257D%252C%257B%2522type%2522%253A%2522TASK_LOG%2522%252C%2522taskId%2522%253A%2522CSB_RUN_OUTSIDE_CONTAINER%253D1%2520devcontainer%2520templates%2520apply%2520--template-id%2520%255C%2522ghcr.io%252Fdevcontainers%252Ftemplates%252Fjavascript-node%255C%2522%2520--template-args%2520%27%257B%257D%27%2520--features%2520%27%255B%255D%27%2522%252C%2522id%2522%253A%2522clufrki4b00if3b6hq2hc5i8o%2522%252C%2522mode%2522%253A%2522permanent%2522%257D%255D%257D%257D%252C%2522showDevtools%2522%253Atrue%252C%2522showShells%2522%253Atrue%252C%2522showSidebar%2522%253Atrue%252C%2522sidebarPanelSize%2522%253A14.513888888888886%257D) that approximates the problem (see "home" tab).